# How to insert bind column and unbind column datagridview values in database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am inserting datagirdview column values into database. Datagridview has 4 columns 1st column is bind to a  table of  database. I have written this query to insert all this data to my table but I am getting error "invalid column name 'w'". Somebody help me to figure it out. In the database table I have these columns: SupplierId, Item, Quantity, PricePerItem,Total,BillNo ..The Query I used is :

```
string q = @" INSERT INTO PurchaseInvo(SupplierId,Item,Quantity,PricePerItem,Total,BillNo) VALUES (" + comboBox1.Text + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Item"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PricePerItem"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value + ", " + bill + ")";
```

Comment: Post the actual sql statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string q = 
@" INSERT INTO PurchaseInvo 
         (SupplierId, Item, Quantity, PricePerItem, Total, BillNo) 
    VALUES 
         (@SupplierID, @Item, @Quantity, @PricePerItem, @Total, @Bill)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, connectionString);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", comboBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Item"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qauntity", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PricePerItem", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PricePerItem"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill", bill);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You should always use sql command parameters. This will prevent you from sql injection and also from errors like this. The code written like this should work.